# REST /customers/me does not return extension_attributes

Tags: magento2, magento-community

According to the interface \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface my response should return the extension_attributes, but it doesn't

Magento 2.2.3 CE

Comment: HI @Philipp Sander did you check in higher version of magento(2.3,2.4).

Comment: did you add attribute in extension attributes?

Comment: @Learing_Coder the project is on 2.2.X

Comment: @Vishnunath I currently have no custom ones, but "is_subscribed" is one from the magento-core

Comment: In order to show in output. You have to add constant variable for 'is_subscribed' in interface file and need to add getter and setter methods and define those methods in respective model file in that case @PhilippSander

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct "is_subscribed" field in Magento core table. they have added field in customer registration form.

while creating customer registration form, if we checked ***is_subscribed*** checkbox, newsletter_subscriber table  ***subscriber_status*** is set to be 1.otherwise it won't save any data in this table.

[image]

So, if we want to set or get custom field in extension attributes, we have to add customized attributes in extension attributes.

Try with following sample code.

**vendor/module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
   <attribute code="is_subscribed" type="int"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

**vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">       
    <plugin name="get_is_subscribed" type="Cloras\Addon\Plugin\CustomerGet"/>        
</type>
```

**vendor/module/Plugin/CustomerGet**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CustomerGet
{
   protected $_customerExtensionFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterfaceFactory $customerExtensionFactory
   ) {
        $this->_customerExtensionFactory = $customerExtensionFactory;
   }


    public function afterGetById(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $resultCustomer
    ) {

        $resultCustomer = $this->getCustomerData($resultCustomer);
        return $resultCustomer;
    }


    protected function getCustomerData(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
        $customerExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->_customerExtensionFactory->create();
        /* Here add own functionality for getting dynamic data*/
        $customerExtension->setIsSubscribed(1); 
        $customer->setExtensionAttributes($customerExtension);

        return $customer;
    }   


    public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $resultCustomer
    ) {
        /** @var  $customer */
        foreach ($resultCustomer->getData() as $customer) {
            $this->afterGet($subject, $customer);
        }
        return $resultCustomer;
    }

}
```

after that remove this ***generated/code/Magento/Customer*** in Magento2 root folder and clear cache to see the results in API.

[http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/customers/2](http://localhost/magento2.2/rest/V1/customers/2)

```
"firstname": "Mav",
        "lastname": "rick",
        "default_shipping": true,
        "default_billing": true
    }
],
"disable_auto_group_change": 0,
"extension_attributes": {
    "is_subscribed": 1
},
```

The **/V1/customers/me** API url calling getById method. so please look into this

```
 <route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: wrong endpoint. I'm talking about customers/me

Comment: @philipp check the edited post. so that i wrote plugin and added into the post for your question. Thanks

Comment: Hi Vishnunath, I had tested your code, I got an error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\Customer\\Api\\Data\\CustomerExtensionInterface"

Solution :: Please replace in Construct "\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterfaceFactory $customerExtensionFactory"  TO "\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory"

Answer (score 1):

> I had tested Above code, I got an error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterface"
>
> Solution :: Please replace in Construct **"\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterfaceFactory $customerExtensionFactory"**  TO  **"\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory"**
>
> I had updated **getCustomerData() function**

```
 <?php
 namespace Custom\CustomerApi\Plugin;

class Customer
 {
protected $_customerExtensionFactory;
protected $logger;
protected $subscriber;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory 
$customerExtensionFactory,\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subscriber, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_customerExtensionFactory = $customerExtensionFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
 }
  public function afterGetById(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $resultCustomer
  ) {

    $resultCustomer = $this->getCustomerData($resultCustomer);
    return $resultCustomer;
}

protected function getCustomerData(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer)
{
    $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
    $customerExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->_customerExtensionFactory->create();
    $checkSubscriber = $this->subscriber->loadByEmail($customer->getEmail());
    if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed())
     {
       $customerExtension->setIsSubscribed(true);
       $customer->setExtensionAttributes($customerExtension);
     }else{
       $customerExtension->setIsSubscribed(false);
       $customer->setExtensionAttributes($customerExtension);
     }
    return $customer;
}   

public function afterGetList(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $resultCustomer
) {
    /** @var  $customer */
    foreach ($resultCustomer->getData() as $customer) {
        $this->afterGet($subject, $customer);
    }
    return $resultCustomer;
}
 }
```